# sys.sp_addextendedproperty in vb.net

Tags: sql, vb.net, stored-procedures

I am attempting to add a colum description to an sql column I am creating, but having an issue.

In SQL Mgmt Studio I did:

```
EXEC sys.sp_addextendedproperty 
@name = N'MS_Description', 
@value = N'test5', 
@level0type = N'SCHEMA', 
@level0name = 'dbo',
@level1type = N'TABLE',  
@level1name = 'tblConfigurationVariables',
@level2type=N'COLUMN',
@level2name=N'test6'
GO
```

And it works right. But when I do it in vb.net (I think right)

```
        objCmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure
        objCmd.CommandText = "sys.sp_addextendedproperty"
        objCmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@name", "N'MS_Description'")
        objCmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@value", "N'" & txtVarDescription.Text & "'")
        objCmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@level0type", "N'SCHEMA'")
        objCmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@level0name", "dbo")
        objCmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@level1type", "N'TABLE'")
        objCmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@level1name", "tblConfigurationVariables")
        objCmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@level2type", "N'COLUMN'")
        objCmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@level2name", txtVarName.Text)
        i = objCmd.ExecuteNonQuery
```

I get the error:

An invalid parameter or option was specified for procedure 'sp_addextendedproperty'.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Note that the `N` prefix for `nvarchar` strings is not *part* of the string in SQL. Nor are the `'` quote marks. They're how a string literal is written in SQL. As such, they shouldn't be appearing in the strings that you're passing:

```
objCmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@name", "MS_Description")
objCmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@value", txtVarDescription.Text)
objCmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@level0type", "SCHEMA")
objCmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@level0name", "dbo")
objCmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@level1type", "TABLE")
objCmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@level1name", "tblConfigurationVariables")
objCmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@level2type", "COLUMN")
objCmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@level2name", txtVarName.Text)
```

Comment: Thanks Damien!  Worked perfectly!